# conditional formatting or formatting with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, readability

In MS Access, is there a reason to prefer conditional formatting over setting formatting options with VBA?  Is one more effecient or generally considered easier to read?

Comment: You mean conditional formatting that is only used in continuous forms and reports as compared to what? I don't quite get what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditional formatting works on continuous forms or subforms.  VBA formatting doesn't work on continuous forms and subforms.   Both work on standard forms.

Comment: But conditional formatting does have that slowness that is like what you get when you put a calculated expression as ControlSource of a form control. It's invaluable because of what it does, but a little quirky in terms of display.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Access or Excel but haven't used VBA, conditional formatting can be preferable because you don't have to learn nearly so much.  I realize this answer is probably not applicable from the asker's point of view, but it may be important to someone with less knowledge generally.